# What CSS property disables the activity in the background of a Bootstrap 4 modal?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, background, bootstrap-modal

I would like to know what property, or sets of properties, can be used to deactivate, blur or even put darker the background behind a Bootstrap modal.

I am interested in using those same properties somewhere else but I am having trouble finding them when using inspect element (developer tools).

Hoping you guys can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A div `.modal-backdrop` is created which is responsible for this... play around to change the color or the opacity of this div

```css
.modal-backdrop {
  background: rgba(161, 247, 174, 0.9) !important;
  opacity: 0.3 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: what about deactivating the activity behind the modal? For instance, in your example, once you open the modal, when scrolling we can only scroll through the modal, the background remains still (taking "Modal Example" header as a reference)

Comment: You want to restrict the background from being scrollable? Is that your question?

Comment: Yes! that's exactly it and way clearer than how I asked it. Thanks

Comment: for this, you'd have to add the CSS property `overflow:hidden` on the `<body>` or the `<html>` tag... and then when closing the modal, remove this css property